# Error when running Screeps game script

Tags: javascript, screeps

Don't know about "Screeps"? Visit screeps.com

It's a second line in main script:

```
var spawnController = require('spawnController');
```

It's error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
at __evalCode:1:10622
at h:1:12286
at main:2:23
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Might be a bug with their interpreter. You should file a bug report with them.

Comment: Thanks, but first line with same code(var harvester = require('harvester');) works...

Comment: Finally find it - error in module 'spawnController'... My fault... :( Thanks anyway - next time i'll edit my question in a proper way.

Comment: If you found the solution, add an answer to your question yourself and mark it as accepted. It's perfectly fine on SO and it might help someone else with a similar problem in the future. Be sure the relevant code to the problem is in the question and a solution to it is in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After 1 hour i was finally find solution - you just need to check all lines of code in required module(not in main). Screeps interpreter points to start of require expression(to 'r' char) if it find some mistakes in module code.
So, be patient and double check all your code...

Comment: Remember to accept your own answer as the correct one.